# How to send event from .Net client to Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, events

I would like my .Net (C#) written executable running in the local machine 
to send an event to a Silverlight object (embedded in ASPX page in remote server).

Is there a simple solution for that issue ? 
Can someone please supply a demo source code (or a link).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, but not as simply as you would like it to be.

> embedded in ASPX page in remote server

Let me clear up one misconception first: the Silverlight control is not embedded in an ASPX page on a remote server. The ASPX page and Silverlight control are *hosted* and *served* by the remote server. The Silverlight control is loaded and rendered on the *client* when the ASPX page is requested by the browser. The Silverlight control does not exist as a concrete instance on the server.

If you want the Silverlight control on a client machine to receive a message from a Windows client app on another machine, then you will need to introduce an intermediary like a WCF web service. This web service can be hosted on the same machine that hosts the web page and silverlight control, and both can send messages to the WCF service, and listen for messages either by regular old-fashioned polling or by using a duplex binding.

For more info on duplex WCF, check out these articles i dug up for you:

- [WCF Duplex Messaging](http://www.dotnetconsult.co.uk/weblog2/PermaLink,guid,b891610a-6b78-4b54-b9a6-4ec81c82b7c0.aspx)
- [MSDN: Silverlight - How to: Access a Duplex Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844557%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)